# Synchronize database between client and app

Tags: java, spring-boot, synchronization, h2

I have the following setup. I have a server, and several applications (Spring boot java apps).
The server and the applications have separate (h2) databases, so that they can do offline work.

The client knows the servers address, but the server does not know the clients address.
How can I synchronize the databases between them?
I thought to implement a schedule table and when the client is online send the data to the server, but than the server can make changes as well....and I have several objects to sync.

Isn't there any out-of-the box solution?
I checked SymmetricDS but the there everybody must know each others address.

Comment: Don't think there is some 'out-of-box' solution, even blind merging of rows as import/export from one database to another will work by default - due to ids sequencing  at least.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I started working on a project that has similar requirements. I haven't fully implemented it but I'll tell you how I planned it out. Here, I assume you have a single database on the online server to synchronize the data from the local applications.

1. Ensure each record (both local and online) has a status properties that shows it has been synchronized. All local records are then marked as unsynchronized during creation or updation.
2. Ensure there's no primary key(p.k) collision in your online databases. For example, applications 1 and 2 might have db tables called "users" that contain records with p.k of 10 each. Because of this, it's advisable to use non-numeric p.k designs like UUID (though with some tradeoffs) for this kind of systems.
3. Since only the local applications that know the address of the online server, Synchronisation is initiated by by the local applications by using Crontasks. Synchronisation can also be user-triggered or the application can listen to network connection and triggers synchronisation when connected.
4. To ensure that data are synchronised properly between the local applications and the online server, bidirectional connection is required. Initial connection requests are made by the local applications since they know the server address. Such connection will help the server to inform a local application about other data collected from another local application.
5. When the online server receives a record from an application, it saves it as synchronised and then informs the local application about the successful save. The local application should mark the record as synchronised before sending it to the online server. When an unsuccessful synchronisation is received by the local application from the online server, the record is marked as unsynchronized. The reason for marking a record as synchronised before sending it to the online server is because the local application may have altered the state of the record before a synchronisation response comes back from the online server. When a local application is done sending unsynchronized data to the online server, the online server starts sending data collected from the other local applications which the current local application does not have already.
6. Even the above setup can be implemented using HTTP request/response approach, it's clear that `RSocket` has more advantages in this application due to its numerous features:

- Connection is bidirectional
- Both ends can serve as client and server by sending requests and receiving responses
- Back pressure to control sending and receipts of data
- Requests and responses are binary data streams, hence speed is guaranteed
- etc.

There are lots of `Rsocket` materials to help you get started in spring boot.
[Here's is the official doc.](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/02/getting-started-with-rsocket-spring-boot-server)
There are wonderful [YouTube videos](https://youtu.be/ipVfRdl5SP0) on it as well by Josh Long.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had a similar requirement from a client. My approach was similar to the approach used by Wilson. But I used numerical id only for the objects.

Below are the details:

1. Each model has 2 additional fields - remoteId and synced. The remoteId is the id of the other server. Whenever any entity is created or updated the synced flag is set to false.
2. Sync gets triggered by the local server using a cron schedular.
3. Local server fetches all non synchronized data(synced=false) and send them to the online server in json format.
4. Remote server receives the data, interchanges the values of id & remoteId, marks synced flag as true and then saves the data.
5. Upon successful processing of the data online server sends an acknowledgement to the local server with the saved id.
6. Once acknowledgement is received, the local server updates the sent object marking the remoteId as online id and synced flag as true.
7. Similarly local server requests online server for any non synced data. The online server fetches all the non synced online data and sends them to local server.
8. Local server saves received data changing the id to remoteId and marking synced flag as true. Once done the local server sends an acknowledgement to the online server with the id of the saved object.
9. Upon receiving acknowledgement, the online server updates the object with received id as remote id and synced flag as true.

For handing the delete sync an entity listener is used. The lister makes a table entry whenever any entity is deleted which has a not null remoteId. The delete records are interchanged between the servers at the time of sync and then processed. Once processing is done the other server is acknowledged and delete sync table data is cleared there.